# Android - How to implement a listbox as a modal dialog/popup

Tags: android, listview, listbox, dialog, spinner

In my Android app, when a user clicks on a button, I want a list box to show up as a modal dialog, just like the way a Spinner works, except that the list box can also allow multiple choices. I tried using ListView as described in the android hello-listview tutorial (http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html). Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work the way I had expected it to. It doesn't show up as a modal dialog like the Spinner. I tried looking at what the Android browser does when a listbox is to be displayed. I browsed to www.functionx.com/html/lesson14.htm in the browser on my Android device and saw the following behavior (and this is exactly the behavior I want in my app):

When a dropdown/combobox in HTML is clicked, a spinner comes up as seen in the image here:

 
http://img842.imageshack.us/img842/803/htmlcombobox.png

When a single select listbox is clicked, again a spinner comes up as seen here: 

http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/3355/listboxsingle.png

And when a multi-select listbox is clicked, a multi-select spinner / listview shows up in a dialog as seen here:

http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/711/listboxmulti.png

So my questions are:

1. What is this widget (in the last image above) that allows multi-select in a modal dialog. I'm sure this must be a component already available on the Android platform since it's being displayed in the browser.
2. Even the Spinners (in the first 2 images) in the browser look different than the default Spinner I'm seeing in my app. Would the browser be applying custom skinning / colors to the background and text of the Spinners that it displays?

Comment: Nevermind the second question.. my app is built for an older version than the OS installed on my device. That explains the different look of the spinners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the ApiDemos sample project, the [AlertDialogSamples activity](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlertDialogSamples.html). There is a button labeled "Repeat alarm" that invokes a modal dialog with a multiple choice list.

In any case, a good place to start would be [`AlertDialog.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html).

Answer (score 15):

Here's the code in case anyone's interested:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.select_dialog_items,
                    new boolean[]{false, true, false, true, false, false, false},
                    new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton,
                                boolean isChecked) {

                            /* User clicked on a check box do some stuff */
                        }
                    })
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    /* User clicked Yes so do some stuff */
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    /* User clicked No so do some stuff */
                }
            })
           .show();
```